# Autocad: how to export a file with XREF to .stl

Tags: autocad

I am trying to export the following .dwg file to .stl format but the object that has been externally referenced does not make into the .stl file.

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

[The files in .dwg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ym2z56ubv68rds6/3d%20file.zip)

Comment: You could always try binding the Xref into the DWG as a block beforehand if you don't need the reference to be live after the conversion.

Comment: i am actually trying to embed it, but don't know how! I have even tried convert the Kinect model dwg to stl, but that doesnt work either, although there is not xref there!

Comment: I just looked at your files.  The Kinect looks to be already loaded as a block in the drawing, however it's going to need to be a solid or a watertight mesh in order to be added to the list of objects included in the .stl export.

Comment: how is that done? could you convert the file to .stl for me please?